# Call a function from a running process

Tags: python, ipc, subprocess

my programm starts a subprocess, which has to send some kind of signal to the parent after initialization. It would be perfekt if i could set up a handler in parent, which is called when this signal is sent. Is there any way to do it?

Alendit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Python 2.6, you can use the `multiprocessing` module from the standard library, in particular pipes and queues. Simple example from the docs:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def f(conn): #This code will be spawned as a new child process
    conn.send([42, None, 'hello']) #The child process sends a msg to the pipe
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(child_conn,)) # prepare to spawn the child
    p.start() # spawn it
    print parent_conn.recv()   # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join() #wait for child to exit
```

If you are using Python 2.4 or 2.5, don't despair - a backport is available [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiprocessing/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, first i was little scared away, because i in fact have to do it with python2.5, but the backports worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Parent code:

```
import signal

def my_callback(signal, frame):
    print "Signal %d received" % (signal,)

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, my_callback)
# start child
```

Child code:

```
import os
import signal

signal.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGUSR1)
```

Be careful with this form of IPC because it has its issues, e.g.:

> In the original Unix systems, when a
>   handler that was established using
>   signal()  was  invoked  by the
>   delivery of a signal, the disposition
>   of the signal would be reset to
>   SIG_DFL, and  the  system  did  not 
>   block delivery  of  further  instances
>   of the signal.  System V also provides
>   these semantics for signal().  This
>   was bad because the signal might be
>   delivered  again before the handler
>   had a chance to reestablish itself.
>   Furthermore, rapid deliveries of the
>   same signal could result in recursive
>   invocations of the handler.

I recommend reading the whole [`signal(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) man page.

Comment: Your solution would be perfekt, if there would be a way to send parameters to parent funktion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [signal module](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) from the Python standard library to register a signal handler. The subprocess would then use normal signal sending mechanisms.