# Call a function in a running program (and a code review)

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, function

**Call a function in a running program**

I am fairly new to programming and recently decided that I want to expand my Python knowledge and practice a bit. For that reason I decided that I create a little Weather Station with a Raspberry PI.

The program I am currently creating takes the output from a thermometer, parses it and writes it into a database. At the time the program is started every minute and after completing the aforementioned procedure, the program ends and all the instances get deleted (is that how you say it?).

I think that restarting it every minute wastes resources and time is getting lost so I want my program to run all the time and be accessible via command line commands (bash).

For example I have the class `Thermometer`:

```
class Thermometer():
    def measure():
        # do stuff
        # return stuff
```

An instance of this class is created like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    thermo = Thermometer
    while True:
        pass
```

Is it possible that I could call the function `measure` like this?:

```
sudo python3 < thermo.measure()
```

Or is there an other way to achieve this or am I doing a completely wrong approach? Also how could one describe this problem? I tried searching for "Python call function from outside" or "Python call function from bash" but I didn't find anything useful except [Call a function from a running process
 StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393242/call-a-function-from-a-running-process) but it seems that this is the wrong Python version.

You can find my code here: [github Jocomol/weatherstation](http://%20https://github.com/Jocomol/weatherstation)

or if you don't trust the link go to github and search for "Jocomol/weatherstation".

**Code review**

As I already mentioned I am quite new to python and programming itself, so I make a lot of mistakes or  writing useless code that could be resolved otherwise. So I am thankful for any feedback I can get on my code. If you guys could take a look at my code and point out places that aren't optimal or where I did something completely useless, I would be very happy.

Comment: Doing what you want is OS-specific and requires non-trivial interprocess communication ([IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)).

Comment: You'll want to create a TCP/IP server and client. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example